# MS Project Custom Field Summary roll up not totalling

Tags: ms-project

I am struggling to see an option in MS Project when using  a custom currency field for the the summary task to total.  It shows a zero and I dont know how to change it.  See screenshot below.  Any help would be great
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the custom Fields screen, be sure to change the **Calculation for task and group summary rows** to **Use formula**.
[image]

Comment: Absolute legend.  thanks for your help.  all sorted now

Comment: Glad that worked for you! FYI: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)